Desktop Monitor: switching from 24" to 32" screen size
Recently, I've tried to switch away from a 24" to a 32" monitor. Unfortunately, after a couple of days testing, I had to return to the 24" due to some kind of eye discomfort related to screen brightness. Here goes my findings ...
I have a couple of 24" monitors which I alternate them in my single-monitor desktop setup (OS: Debian GNU/Linux):

SAMSUNG T24B350
LG 24MN33N-PS

They are all great at 2~3 ft viewing distances but weak to watch movies at 4~6 ft.
This motivated me to try a larger monitor that could improve my experience at 4~6 ft but still be as comfortable at 2~3 ft. This lead me to the following 32" monitor:

H-BUSTER HBTV-32D03HD

For my surprise, my first impression was reasonably good:

The extra eye movement from one corner to another did not cause any issue.
The extra space was helpful to open multiple windows.
Easier to see small objects (ex: small icons and fonts) even farther away.
Watch movies at 4~6 ft was much better!

However, after a while, I started to notice the following issue:

The screen brightness must be considerably reduced otherwise white objects can really hurt your eyes (specially when the background switches from dark to light).
I've tried to adjust the screen setting both via the monitor menu (ie: backlight, brightness, contrast) and via Linux tools (ex: ddccontrol, xgamma). However, I did not find a permanent setting that could handle a wide range of image brightnesses, as I could do with the 24" monitors. All the time I had to manually adjust the brightness setting according to the content being displayed.

After a couple of days, this issue was intolerable and really uncomfortable for my eyes. So much that I decided to switch back to the 24" monitor.
Questions

Any idea what might be causing the issue above?

250 cd/m² increased to 420 cd/m²
Notice that the brightness of the 24" monitors are both 250 cd/m² while the 32" monitor is 420 cd/m².
Could this be the main reason of the issue above?

TV vs PC Monitor
Notice that all monitors are considered TVs instead of dedicated PC monitors.
Could this influence somehow the issue above?

HD ready instead of Full HD
Notice that the maximum resolution of the 32" monitor is 1366x768 instead of 1920x1080.
Could this influence somehow the issue above?

Important Specs for Large Monitors
All over the net people are building desktop setups with large monitors (ie: 32~48 inches) and succeeding.
What specifications need extra attention in order to avoid the discomfort discussed above and enhance the overall experience?



Hardware Specifications
SAMSUNG HDTV Monitor SyncMaster 24"
Source: Samsung User Manual, Hardstore, B&H

Model Name: LT24B530

Screen Size: 24"

Power Consumption: 40W

Display Resolution: 1920x1080 @60Hz

Contrast Ratio: 1000:1 (Static) | Mega ∞ DCR (Dynamic)

Brightness: 250 cd/m²

Response Time: 5 ms

Viewing Angle (H/V): 170º/160º

Display Type: TN LED


LG TV Monitor 24"
Source: LG Electronics

Model Name: 24MN33N-PS

Screen Size: 24"

Power Consumption: 33W

Maximum Resolution: 1366x768 @60Hz

Contrast Ratio: 50.000:1

Brightness: 250 cd/m²

Response Time: 8,5 ms

Viewing Angle (H/V): 178º/178º

Type: TV Monitor LED LCD

Color Support: 16,7Mi

Screen Coating: Non Glare


H-BUSTER TV LCD 32"
Source: DMSHOP

Model Name: HBTV-32D03HD
Screen Size: 32"
Power Consumption: 115W max
Display Resolution: 1366x768 @60Hz
Contrast Ratio: 3.000:1 (Static)
Brightness: 420 cd/m²
Response Time: 6,5 ms
Viewing Angle (H/V): 178º/178º


no two monitors are really the same - if you're running windows, its worth trying the 'caliberate display colour' wizard to 'tune' your monitor to your liking, if you're not going to go full overkill and run a hardware colour caliberation tool


I'm not using a dual-monitor setup. The aforementioned monitors were tested, one at a time, in my single-monitor setup. 2) I'm using Linux. 3) If I calibrate all these monitors to the same color, would the aforementioned "brightness fatigue" disappear?


More of visually similar enough settings or at least comfortable ones. Basically that tool walks you through settings based on what image settings you prefer.I think there are web based alternatives too. Basically applying a little more organized tweaking to the problem

You bought a TV, and a cheap one at that. According to online resources, it’s not 1080p at all, but instead “HD ready”, 1366×768. At 32″, this is a ridiculously low resolution for non-movie contents. If it displays a 1080p computer image, there will be lots of artifacts from downscaling, which could cause eye strain/fatigue.
Independent from that, TVs are simply optimized for a different use case. As such, they will not offer the required control over image quality and brightness required for use as a computer display. If you want a 32″ display for your PC, get a computer display.
Disregarding all that, a flat panel display’s backlight could be flickering, a phenomenon also present in “real” computer displays. Some people are sensitive to this and experience eye strain.

As stared above, and at http://www.dmshop.com.br/h-buster-tv-32-lcd-h-buster-hbtv-32d03hd-c-entradas-hdmi-e-usb-e-conversor-digital.html, that is poor resolution for close work.


I did not bought it. It was going to the scrap.   2) Indeed the box states "HD-Ready - 1366x768". However, when the HDMI is plugged, the screen info states "1920x1080 @60Hz". Mind to reconcile?   3) The 24" monitors are also described as "TV monitors".  4) The max resolution of the LG monitor seems to be also 1366x768. Only the Samsung monitor seems to have a max resolution of 1920x1080.    5) Mind to give more details about the advantages of buying a specific "PC Monitor" and what specs I should pay attention in order to avoid such "brightness fatigue" ??   tks anyway !!


@DrMoishePippik  The max resolution of the 24" LG monitor is 1366x768  while the max resolution of the 24" Samsung monitor is 1920x1080. However I see no meaningful resolution difference between them. Mind to reconcile?

"HD ready" means it accepts up to 1080P, NOT that is its maximum real, native, resolution. When receiving a 1080P it'll always downscale it to its actual 1366x768 resolution (i.e. it "transforms" 1920x1080 into 1366x768). This is a simple thing to understand, nothing to reconcile.

@ChanganAuto > "This is a simple thing to understand, nothing to reconcile." | The reconciliation I asked for was regarding the screen info stating "1920x1080 @60Hz". It seems misleading since this is not the actual resolution.

Again... That message is regarding the input it is receiving.

@ChanganAuto > "That message is regarding the input it is receiving." | Is this an industry standard?  For example, those new 4K TV would also show only 720p when upscaling from 720p to 4K?

Yes, it's an industry standard. No, a 4K TV reproducing 720P does NOT upsacale because 1280x720 is one of the SUPPORTED resolutions.
